# How do I get my icon to show on the taskbar panel for a program?

Tags: centos

I downloaded Mozilla Thunderbird and extracted the tar file I was given and ran the program using the terminal command line. I asked a previous question on how to create a shortcut for it so that I could add it to my favorites section here.

[image]

I was able to create this shortcut but I noticed the icon is not displayed on the taskbar(bottom panel) where it shows all the current programs running at the bottom but it does in the application search as well as in the favorites section. All it shows is the Thunderbird tab and the space where the icon would be is just blank. Is there another field I have to set in the .desktop file besides the icon field? I'm on Centos 7.

This is the .desktop file for it

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Thunderbird
Comment=Mozilla Thunderbird Email Application
Icon=/home/username/Thunderbird/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Exec=/home/username/Thunderbird/thunderbird
Terminal=false
Categories=
```